# Trying to get a hover transition working for background alpha

Tags: css

I am trying to make a circle of color appear around my navigation buttons. CSS looks like this right now:

```
.nav-btn {
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(70, 48, 70, 0);
}
.nav-btn :hover {
  background-color: rgba(70, 48, 70, 1);
  transition: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

... it looks like this when I hover:

[hover image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMz6u.png)

Am I just going about this the wrong way entirely?

I'd prefer answers that use only html and css as I haven't earned javascript yet.

Comment: There should be no space between these: `.nav-btn:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is with the hover. It should be `.nav-btn:hover` not `.nav-btn :hover` doing that should fix the hover issue.

Comment: That has completely fixed it. Thank you so much!